# What is the meaning of "$this->object->..." in php?

Tags: php, abstract-class

I am working on a php script where this syntax is used (and it seems to work properly) inside an abstract class:

```
$this->object->prepareTextareaOutput()
```

and i cant find the place where the method `prepareTextareaOutput()` is defined, neither inside the abstract class itself nor in classes which use it as parent class.

Please help!

Comment: it's calling a method of the "object" class referenced in "$this"?

Comment: You mean the `$object` property (class variable), you don't know its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->foobar

is an attribute (variable) of your current object, referenced by `$this`.
So if `$this->foobar` is an object and foobar has a method `baz()`, you can call it by `$this->foobar->baz()`. It is the same as

```
$tmp=$this->foobar;
$tmp->baz();
```

Find the definition of $object in your current class. If it says `$this->object = new user;` (e.g.), you will find the method in the class user.

Comment: lol it seems i was confused by the word "object" and notepad++ did not really help by highlighting it as a keyword!!! I definitively have to get more practice in php! Tanks a lot so far :-)

Comment: Welcome. In the long term you might want to use a full-fledged IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse. (To name some free ones.)

Answer (score 3):

`$this->object` is a reference to another class instance.

Use `var_dump(get_class($this->object));` to get its class name.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitively korrekt answer too, but have not enough rep to mark it as useful :\